# Can I use Django in a way that I can change CSS variables?

Tags: python, html, css, django

I am creating a personal website and I have a progress bar that has been done in css and html.

in order to control the progress bars all I need to do is change a variable(width).
This is the code for one bar:

```
.bar-inner1 {
  width: 559px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  background: #db3a34;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
```

This is the corresponding html that is affected by this css:

```
<div class="container">
  <h2 class="my-skills">My Skills</h2>
  <div class="bar-1">
  <div class="title">HTML5</div>
  <div class="bar" data-width="65%">
    <div class="bar-inner1">

    </div>
    <div class="bar-percent">65%</div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

How would I use Django to change the variable width?

I have looked through documentation and tutorials but I cannot seem to work it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use inline CSS to change `width`, like

```
<div class="container">
  <h2 class="my-skills">My Skills</h2>
  <div class="bar-1">
  <div class="title">HTML5</div>
  <div class="bar" data-width="65%">
    <div class="bar-inner1" style="width: {{ progress|default:0 }}%;">

    </div>
    <div class="bar-percent">{{ progress|default:0 }}%</div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Here you should need to set the width of the parent `div` in some 'px' and the progress's background colour will be correct according to its percentage

```
.bar{
  width: 500px;
  height: 35px;
  background: #acacac;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
.bar-inner1 {
  height: 35px;
  background: #db3a34;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
```

If that `progress` variable is not passed in the context then the value there should be `None` to replace that with `0` I used a predefined template tag `default`

Answer (score 0):

You can use inline CSS for that. Just use in inline css same you use in HTML.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Django to generate the initial width of the progress bar, using Context data and Template logic, but once the page is sent to the client Django can't influence it anymore..
You'd have to use Javascript/Jquery and if you *really* need some value from Django you'd ping the server with Ajax or refresh the page.